# How to get Maven plugin to use Eclipse workspace resolution?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm developing a Maven plugin. It's going to be used during development, and it would greatly increase our productivity if the plugin would include -SNAPSHOT projects in Eclipse on the classpath. In other words, use Eclipse workspace resolution instead of getting the artifacts for these other projects out of the repository.

I tried to set this annotation in the plugin:

```
@requiresDependencyResolution compile
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I am using m2eclipse. Maven/Enable workspace resolution is turned on. It's also turned on in the Run Configuration I'm using.

Comment: If you really developing a Maven Plugin you should think about using Maven Invoker Plugin for doing integration tests. The problem you will get inside Eclipse, cause Eclispe uses a kind of Maven-Embedder which is around Maven-3.0-Alpha-3 etc...